# May I use cli() and sei() in the interrupt?

Tags: c++, interrupt, avr

May I use cli() and sei() like this:

```
ISR(EXT_INT0_vect)
{
    cli();
    MyFunction();
    sei();
}
```

I heard that it is forbidden. Is it or I can use cli() and sei() like above?

Comment: I think you need to [edit] in more detail of what you're trying to do. I've never used AVR, but from [here](https://www.avrfreaks.net/forum/clisei-what-are-they), `cli()` prevents interrupts from occurring (and `sei()` enables them)... however, from [here](https://www.avrfreaks.net/sites/default/files/Interrupt.pdf) (PDF), interrupts are _already_ disabled inside an ISR so doing what you're doing doesn't seem to make much sense.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Calling cli() and sei() manually (like in your example) is redundant if you want normal interrupt behavior. That is, because AVR automatically clears the global interrupt flag before the ISR is executed.
There are rare use cases for nested interrupts, where you may want to manually re-enable interrupts using sei() within the ISR.

From [Nested interrupts](http://ucexperiment.wordpress.com/2013/05/20/nested-interrupts/):

> Normally, the AVR hardware clears the global interrupt flag (in SREG)
> before entering an interrupt. This means other interrupts are disabled
> inside the running handler until the handler finishes and exits.
>
> The RETI instruction is the normal function epilogue for an interrupt
> handler, and thus re-enables interrupts (just like executing an SEI
> instruction).   For this reason, normally, interrupt handlers can not
> be nested.
>
> For most interrupt handlers, this is the desired behavior. For some
> its even required in order to prevent infinitely recursive interrupts.
> Recursion could easily exceed the available stack space and crash the
> running program. In rare circumstances it might be desirable to
> re-enable the global interrupt flag as early as possible inside the
> interrupt handler, allowing recursive interrupt handling. Carefully.
>
> This could be accomplished by inserting an sei() instruction right at
> the beginning of the interrupt handler, but this still leaves a few
> instructions inside the (compiler-generated) interrupt prologue to run
> with global interrupts disabled. [...]

Answer (score 3):

Calling `sei()` within an interrupt callback (directly or indirectly) is going to prematurely re-enable interrupts.

For this reason many library functions (which may be called from either the main task or from an interrupt handler) save the interrupt mask before disabling interrupts, and then restore the previous interrupt mask instead of blindly enabling it.